# What class in java is never imported

Tags: java

I'm learning java by myself and read a question in a book which states: "which java class never needs to be imported."  Can anyone help me?

Comment: which java class, specify clearly?

Comment: It doesn't specify.  That's the question.  sorry

Comment: I don't think you need to explicitly include anything in `java.lang`, it's included automatically by the compiler.  So `String` for example

Comment: There is no single answer to this question. It is therefore ill-formed.

Comment: java.lang is the answer.  Thanks, all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`java.lang.*` is always automatically imported.

This contains classes like `System`, `Object`, `String`, `Math`, etc.

[Here are the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class that every other class derives from. Other examples are `String`, `System` and the autoboxing classes (`Integer`, `Boolean` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a package? The `java.lang` package is automatically imported in any Java program. Please read [this](http://www.rapidprogramming.com/questions-answers/Which-Package-is-automatically-imported-in-any-Java-Program--246) for more information.